# Help in entropy/probability question

Tags: probability, entropy

I didn't put all solving, but this is a part of solving of an activity in my book

-1/15 [3 log(1/5) + 4 log(4/15) + 8 log(8/15)]

-1/15[-3 log(5) + 4 (log⁡ 4 - log 15) + 8 (log 8 - log 15)]

**-1/15[-3 log(5) - 4 log(3x5) - 8 log(3x5) + 4log(2)^2 + 8 log(2)^3]**

**1/15[ 15 log(5) + 12 log(3) - 32]**

Then the rest of the ⁡solve ....

How did he get from the first (bold statement) to the second (bold statement)?

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Since $log$ is $\log_2$, the last two terms are $8$ and $24$ which gives $32$. The terms involving $\log({3\times 5})$ are expanded into $\log{3} + \log{5}$. Finally, the minus sign is distributed from the outside to the brackets.

Comment: Wowww, I spend two hours trying to get it and here you are made me understand it in just two minutes!!! Thank you soooo much.